# LINQ to XML nested elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can read the XML and return the Order Element.

I also need to return the ShippingAddress with is nested in the Order Element. (Name, AddressLine1, City, PostalCode, CountryCode, Phone) at the same time from the XML Response.

Please can someone show me how to reach the ShippingAddress at the same time.

My current code is

```
private static IEnumerable<FormsPersistence> Addresses(XContainer doc)
    {
        XNamespace ns = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";

        return from address in doc.Descendants(ns + "Order")
               select new FormsPersistence
               {
                   AmazonOrderId = (string)address.Element(ns + "AmazonOrderId").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   PurchaseDate = (string)address.Element(ns + "PurchaseDate").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   BuyerName = (string)address.Element(ns + "BuyerName").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   BuyerEmail = (string)address.Element(ns + "BuyerEmail").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   OrderStatus = (string)address.Element(ns + "OrderStatus").Value ?? string.Empty,
               };
    }

    private static void OrderDetails(IEnumerable<FormsPersistence> addresses)
    {


        foreach (var address in addresses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine(address.AmazonOrderId);
            Console.WriteLine(address.PurchaseDate);
            Console.WriteLine(address.BuyerName);
            Console.WriteLine(address.BuyerEmail);
            Console.WriteLine(address.OrderStatus);
            Console.WriteLine("---");
        }
    }
```

The XML Response is

```
<ListOrdersResult>
<CreatedBefore>10/23/2017 14:09:56</CreatedBefore>
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <AmazonOrderId>026-000000-000000</AmazonOrderId>
    <PurchaseDate>10/20/2017 13:45:17</PurchaseDate>
    <LastUpdateDate>10/20/2017 14:16:38</LastUpdateDate>
    <OrderStatus>Unshipped</OrderStatus>
    <FulfillmentChannel>MFN</FulfillmentChannel>
    <SalesChannel>Amazon.co.uk</SalesChannel>
    <ShipServiceLevel>Std UK Dom_1</ShipServiceLevel>
    <ShippingAddress>
      <Name>kkkkk kkkk</Name>
      <AddressLine1>22 kkkkk road</AddressLine1>
      <City>London</City>
      <PostalCode>SW14 JBD</PostalCode>
      <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
      <Phone>0000000000</Phone>
    </ShippingAddress>
    <OrderTotal>
      <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      <Amount>46.00</Amount>
    </OrderTotal>
    <NumberOfItemsShipped>0</NumberOfItemsShipped>
    <NumberOfItemsUnshipped>6</NumberOfItemsUnshipped>
    <PaymentExecutionDetail />
    <PaymentMethod>Other</PaymentMethod>
    <PaymentMethodDetails>
      <PaymentMethodDetail>Standard</PaymentMethodDetail>
    </PaymentMethodDetails>
    <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
    <BuyerEmail>kkkkk@kkkkk.amazon.co.uk</BuyerEmail>
    <BuyerName>kkk akkkk</BuyerName>
    <ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>Standard</ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>
    <ShippedByAmazonTFM>False</ShippedByAmazonTFM>
    <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
    <EarliestShipDate>10/23/2017 00:00:00</EarliestShipDate>
    <LatestShipDate>10/24/2017 23:59:59</LatestShipDate>
    <EarliestDeliveryDate>10/25/2017 00:00:00</EarliestDeliveryDate>
    <LatestDeliveryDate>10/27/2017 23:59:59</LatestDeliveryDate>
    <IsBusinessOrder>False</IsBusinessOrder>
    <IsPrime>False</IsPrime>
    <IsPremiumOrder>False</IsPremiumOrder>
    <IsReplacementOrder>False</IsReplacementOrder>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

The Class Files

```
class FormsPersistence
{
    public string AmazonOrderId { get; set; }
    public string MerchantOrderID { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string ASIN { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string BuyerName { get; set; }
    public string BuyerEmail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and I added

```
class ShippingAddress
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: But where you want to put the Shipping address in the result, is a property of `FormsPersistence`?

Comment: Yes I have them set in FormsPersitence like  public string Name { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well supposing that `FormsPersistence` has a property to save that, you can do the following:

```
  return from address in doc.Descendants(ns + "Order")
         let shipping=address.Element(ns+"ShippingAddress")
         select new FormsPersistence
           {
               AmazonOrderId = (string)address.Element(ns + "AmazonOrderId").Value ?? string.Empty,
               PurchaseDate = (string)address.Element(ns + "PurchaseDate").Value ?? string.Empty,
               BuyerName = (string)address.Element(ns + "BuyerName").Value ?? string.Empty,
               BuyerEmail = (string)address.Element(ns + "BuyerEmail").Value ?? string.Empty,
               OrderStatus = (string)address.Element(ns + "OrderStatus").Value ?? string.Empty,
               ShippingAddress= new ShippingAddress{Name=(string)shipping.Element(ns+"Name"),
                                                    AddressLine=(string)shipping.Element(ns+"AddressLine1"),
                                                   }
           };
```

You need to use `Element` method, which allows you to get a inner element of the current node, and with the help of `let` clause you can save the result to use it later in your projection as I show in the code above.

Comment: I get The type or namespace name 'ShippingAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) highlighted in VS on new ShippingAddress

Comment: Yes, I was supposing you have a property in your model with that name (which is a custom class), if you don't have it you can create it or add the properties to save the shipping information directly in you `FormPersistence` class

Comment: Sorry for my basic knowledge I'm learning as I go. I added a new class ShippingAddress with in this I added Name and AddressLine. I now get Cannot implicitly convert type 'AmazonMWS.src.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.ShippingAddress' to 'string'

Comment: You need the namespace for shipping: `let shipping=address.Element(ns 
 + "ShippingAddress")`

Comment: Look at the query, I'm creating a new instance of `ShippingAddress`: `new ShippingAddress{}`, I'm not doing directly `ShippingAddress= (string)shipping.Element(...) `

Comment: i'm trying to work out where to add the namespace my class looks like namespace AmazonMWS.src.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders
{
    class ShippingAddress
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
      }
}

Comment: Please don't post that as a comment, edit your question and add the classes, but I guess the issue is because you have not declared yet a property in the `FormPersistence` class, like `public ShippingAddress ShippingAddress {get;set;}`

Comment: Sorry for adding code to comment. I've now edited the question with the class

Comment: The type of `ShippingAddress` property in `FormPersistence` is `string`, please change it to `ShippingAddress` like I said in my previous comment

Comment: thanks - I now get 'AmazonMWS.src.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.FormsPersistence.ShippingAddress' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: you need to declare your class as public: `public class ShippingAddress`, a simple query on google would solved that ;)

Comment: you're welcome, next time add the model (your classes) since the beginning, you will save time and there are people that start downvoting if the question is incomplete. You need to make sure next time that info to solve the problem is already there

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use Elements and then use FirstOrDefault()

```
return doc.Descendants(ns + "Order").Select(address => new FormsPersistence()
               {
                   AmazonOrderId = (string)address.Element(ns + "AmazonOrderId").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   PurchaseDate = (string)address.Element(ns + "PurchaseDate").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   BuyerName = (string)address.Element(ns + "BuyerName").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   BuyerEmail = (string)address.Element(ns + "BuyerEmail").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   OrderStatus = (string)address.Element(ns + "OrderStatus").Value ?? string.Empty,
                   ShippingAddress = address.Elements(ns + "ShippingAddress").Select(shipping => new {
                        name = (string)shipping.Element(ns + "Name")
                   }).FirstOrDefault() 
               }).ToList();
```